# Number of permutations which have the same Kendall-Tau distance

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, permutations

**Input:** The number of elements $m$ and an (positive) integer distance $d$.
**Ouput:** The number of permutations of $m$ elements which have Kendall-Tau distance $d$ from a fixed permutation.

I think there should be a closed formula. Does anybody know a good reference?

Comment: The Kendall-Tau distance is also known as the bubble-sort distance. Does [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948341/dynamic-programming-number-of-ways-to-get-at-least-n-bubble-sort-swaps) answer your question?

Comment: It does! Although not as easy as I hoped, it provides a nice polynomial-time algorithm which should be sufficient for my application. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does [this sequence in OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=+kendall+tau&sort=&language=english&go=Search) help?

Comment: @mrm comment-> answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948341/dynamic-programming-number-of-ways-to-get-at-least-n-bubble-sort-swaps) answers your question. You might also be interested in [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=+kendall+tau&sort=&language=english&go=Search).